# Special value of Hecke $L$ function

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, l-functions

Let $E:y^2＝x^3-x/ \Bbb{Q}(i)$ be elliptic curve and $L(E,1)$ be a special value of $L$ function of $E$ at $1$.

Let $L(ψ,1)$ be value at $1$ of Hecke $L$ function with respect to Hecke character $ψ$, It is known that $L(E,1)＝L( \bar{ψ},1)L(ψ,1)$.

In this case, why $L(ψ,1)＝1$ ?

I may forget some trivial fact about Hecke $L$ character.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the formula $L(E,1)＝L( \bar{\psi},1)L(\psi,1)$ is simply not true.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it was answered. In the original version of the question, $E$ was regarded over $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: The question I wanted to ask was over $ \Bbb{Q}(i)$, and if over $ \Bbb{Q}$(sorry for my first typo), my question had little thing to consider, so I edited.

Comment: Anyway, over $ \Bbb{Q}(i)$ was what I intended. And there is still no answer to this question.

Comment: @dandelion We answered your question. There is a certain Hecke character $\psi$ of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $L(s,E/\mathbb{Q})=L(s,\psi)$ and $L(s,E/\mathbb{Q}(i))=L(s,\psi)L(s,\bar\psi)$. I even gave you a precise reference. Your other question "why $L(1,\psi)=1$?" is hard to answer, because $L(1,\psi)\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Sorry to bother, is  $L(s,E/ \Bbb{Q})＝L(s,\bar{ψ}) $ true?

Comment: Yes, we have $L(s,E/\mathbb{Q})=L(s,\psi)=L(s,\bar\psi)$. In general, for any Hecke character $\psi$ of any number field, $L(s,\bar\psi)$ can be obtained from $L(s,\psi)$ by complex conjugating the Dirichlet coefficients. In the case of $L(s,E/\mathbb{Q})$, the Dirichlet coefficients are real by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear what you mean by $\varphi$ or $\psi$. At any rate, $E$ is a CM curve, hence $L(s,E)$ equals $L(s,\psi)$ for a suitable Hecke character $\psi$ of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. You can find the details (e.g. the definition of $\psi$) in Sections 8.3-8.4 of Iwaniec's book "Topics in classical automorphic forms".

**Added.** As David Loeffler pointed out, if $E$ is regarded as a curve over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, its $L$-function is not $L(s,\psi)$ but $L(s,\psi)L(s,\bar\psi)$. In my answer, $E$ was regarded as a curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, as was in the original question (cf. [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/426910/revisions)).

Comment: What is 'suitable' character ? Here, is the suitable character is  $ \bar{ψ}$ where $ψ$ is usual Hecke character ? Why does that holds ?

Comment: @dandelion There are infinitely many Hecke characters associated with the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. One of them, call it $\psi$, satisfies $L(s,E)=L(s,\psi)$. The complex conjugate of $\psi$, denoted by $\bar\psi$, is another Hecke character associated with the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, but it does not participate in the equation. Why does $L(s,E)=L(s,\psi)$ hold? Well, you need to read the proof, e.g. in Iwaniec's book.

Comment: @dandelion Note also that elliptic curve people like to normalize $L(s,E)$ so that $s=1$ is the center, and the functional equation relates $s$ to $2-s$. This is a bad convention. The correct normalization is that $s=1/2$ is the center, and the functional equation relates $s$ to $1-s$. So, most likely, your $L(1,E)$ is $L(1/2,E)$ with the proper normalization. The two normalizations are connected by the shift $s\mapsto s+1/2$.

Comment: @GHfromMO you say the character $\overline{\psi}$ is not part of the equation relating the $L$-functions of $E$ and $\psi$. While you meant to say $L(s,E)$ is not $L(s,\psi)L(s,\overline{\psi})$, in fact you could use either $\psi$ or $\overline{\psi}$ individually since $L(s,\psi) = L(s,\overline{\psi})$ despite $\psi \not= \overline{\psi}$. It is an analytic analogue of ${\rm N}(\alpha) = {\rm N}(\overline{\alpha})$ for all Gaussian integers $\alpha$ and in fact that property is part of the explanation of the equality of the $L$-functions.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks for your comment. Another way to explain this is that $L(s,E)$ is self-dual (i.e. the Dirichlet coefficients are real).

Comment: @GHfromMO Re your last-but-one comment: I would strongly disagree with the view you advance about the "proper" normalisation for $L$-functions; but I would also contend that it has nothing whatsoever to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @GHfromMO making the center of the functional equation $s=1$ for elliptic curve $L$-functions is not a *bad* convention, just a different one. Making the center $s=1$ gives the Dirichlet series integral coefficients, but making it $s=1/2$ introduces a factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ in the $n$th coefficient, and it is reasonable to consider that ugly. Your comment would be like saying for Gaussian integers $\alpha$ that $|\alpha|$ is a good way to measure the size of $\alpha$ but using its square $|\alpha|^2$ is bad, even though that square is an integer and in fact is the norm of $\alpha$, which is nice.

Comment: I think this answer is actually wrong, since it depends on how you interpret "$L(E, 1)$". The original question states that $E$ is considered as a curve over $K = \mathbf{Q}(i)$, and the equation $L(E/K, s) = L(\psi, s) L(\bar\psi, s)$ is actually correct. It is also true that $E$ descends to $\mathbf{Q}$ and we have $L(E/\mathbf{Q}, s) = L(\psi, s)$, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Also, the integer $|\alpha|^2$ is $|\mathbf Z[i]/(\alpha)|$ for nonzero $\alpha$: a great combinatorial interpretation! Saying only $s=1/2$ is the right normalization for the center is like saying the only good Hecke characters are unitary ones (all values on the unit circle).

Comment: @KConrad: "Do not feed the troll..."

Comment: @DavidLoeffler oops, I was thinking all along that $E$ is  defined over $\mathbf Q$! I am on mobile, so could not easily see the OP’s question while typing my comments here.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Of course normalization is a matter of taste and convention. I take the point of view that without a uniform normalization there is confusion. As far as we know, every reasonable $L$-function (in arithmetic) can be built up from automorphic $L$-functions. For most automorphic representations the most natural way to define the $L$-function makes $s=1/2$ the center.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Let me defend myself and KConrad: In the original question, $E$ was regarded over $\mathbb{Q}$. The OP changed $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, see https://mathoverflow.net/posts/426910/revisions

Comment: @KConrad See my last comment.

Comment: @KConrad Yes, I meant unitary Hecke characters. For many of us, character means a (continuous) homomorphism into the unit circle. In general, my comment was about $L(s,\pi)$ where $\pi$ is an automorphic representation with a unitary central character. The functional equation for such an $L$-function should relate $s$ to $1-s$, out of respect for Riemann and to restore harmony in the universe.

Comment: @KConrad Of course I don't buy the argument that integer Dirichlet coefficients are nice, and it should dictate the normalization. As far as we know, most automorphic $L$-functions have transcendental Dirichlet coefficients, no matter how we normalize them.

Comment: And I must admit that seeing the two neutral elements of the ring of integers on the boundaries of the critical strip is really aesthetically appealing. There might even be some hidden structure appearing through swapping its two composition laws accordingly, if we see the involution in the functional equation as some kind of "inner twist" the L-function could keep track of.

Comment: @KConrad > 
Saying only $s=1/2$
 is the right normalization for the center is like saying the only good Hecke characters are unitary ones…. This made me laugh harder than it should’ve